# Isabelle 'fun' without 'where'?

Tags: isabelle

Isabelle doesn't let me write just `fun f :: "nat list => nat"`; I have to add at least one defining equation, e.g. `where "f [] = 5"`. But since it's fine to leave *some* constructors undefined, why can't I simply leave *all* constructors undefined? Then, a `fun f` without a `where` would be a handy alternative to the `consts f` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I do not see why *`fun f` without `where` is a handy alternative to `consts f`*. You have the latter at your disposal (but also have to specify a type), use it if you must. Moreover, `consts` is more primitive than commands like `definition`, `fun`, and -- in my opinion -- shouldn't be used in production code.

As for your comment on leaving constructors undefined inside a `fun`ction declaration. The wording "undefined" is misleading here, since, e.g., after

```
fun f :: "'a list => nat"
where
  "f [] = 0"
```

you can *prove* that

```
lemma "f (x#xs) = undefined"
  by (cases "x#xs" rule: f.elims) simp
```

and thus `f (x#xs)` is, in some sense, defined to be the value `undefined`. In contrast, after

```
consts f :: "'a list => nat"
```

you cannot proof anything about `f`. You just told the system that there is a constant `f` of a certain type, but without saying anything further about it.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I hadn't realised the distinction between being defined as 'undefined' and not being defined, so thanks for clarifying that.  My comment about 'a handy alternative' stemmed simply from the idea that when working in a 'top-down' way, it's handy to declare a function without having to immediately define it.